# Permutations of a string with two distinct characters (60 of one value and 20 of another)

Tags: python

Here is what I want. If I have 6 A's and 2 B's, how do I get all of the possible combinations?

EX: 
`AAAAAABB, AAAAABAB, AAAABAAB, AAABAAAB, AABAAAAB, ABAAAAAB, BAAAAAAB, etc`

I am really looking to do this with 60 A's and 20 B's and then find the number of times that there is BB somewhere in the results. I would post a bounty to it right now if I could.

Comment: Think about it - you can do this with pen and paper....

Comment: I can do it when I have 60 A's and 20 B's? Then I search through that large data set for BB?

Comment: A cartesian product is something else entirely!

Comment: Note that for the 60+20 case there are going to be 80! elements in your result, which is about 7 * 10^118. Your program is going to take a long time.

Comment: I didn't know exactly what I wanted. I tried to label it the best I could. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You're going to have to work this out with maths, because the number of actual results is going to be huge and time-consuming to compute.  You need to be more specific too.  Are you saying that a single result containing any number of occurrences of `BB` counts as 1?  And does `BB` have to be bracketed by `A` or the edges of the string, or does `BBB` also count as `BB`?

Comment: David - I am sure it will be very slow. I just need to run it once. However, I am very open to suggestions on how to get what I need. I just need to find the number of times B will show up at least one time consecutively for all of the combinations of 60 A's and 20 B's.

Comment: For example 
AAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAABB = 1
AAAAAAAAABBAAAAAAAAAAAA = 1
AAAAABAAAAABAAAAABAAAAA = 0

Comment: Will a `BBB` count as one consecutive match or two?

Comment: @Neil How about you work out the total number of combinations, and then subtract the number of times that `B` *doesn't* occur consecutively.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/ would probably give you a much more practical answer in this case

Comment: paddy - That would work as well. I only just started learning python this week, so I am very new. I want to end up with:

(number of times B shows up at least once consecutively) / (total unique combinations)

Comment: Sorry, I was being a bit sarcastic. Your program won't ever finish for the large data set. Think about it: your program is running about 2 GHz, or 2 billion cycles per second. Even if you could examine one per cycle, you would need 10^109 seconds to look at all of them.

Comment: I think if I only get the unique values it will hopefully be faster.

Comment: OK. There are 80 choose 20 possible combinations, which is about 10^18. That's still a pretty big number.

Comment: Forget about Python and get a book on Algorithms (Cormen or Skiena). Or at least ditch the approach of "let me code it first", it would only work for toy problems. For any potentially useful problem, you need to think it through first. Computers are good for counting, but they don't replace thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.permutations`:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
for p in permutations('AAAAAA'+'LL'):
    print ("".join(p))
...
```

Use `sets` if you want unique items:

```
unique=set(i for  i in permutations('AAAAAA'+'LL'))
```

To get the number of items that contain 'LL' anywhere use `sum` and a generator expression:

```
sum('LL' in "".join(i) for i in permutations('AAAAAA'+'LL'))
```

Comment: I am having trouble with the "". It is giving me an invalid syntax error.

Comment: @Neil are you using Python 3.x ? If so, then use `print("".join(p))`

Comment: @Neil, don't copy and paste this text. Type it, you probably have an encoding problem.

Comment: @Neil: a=set([i for  i in permutations('AAAAAA'+'LL')])

Comment: From there, how can I get the number of times I get 'L',L' consecutively?

Comment: @Neil Do you've a specific question?

Comment: @Neil use `len([i for  i in permutations('AAAAAA'+'LL') if 'LL' in "".join(i)]`).

Comment: @Neil or `sum('LL' in "".join(i) for i in permutations('AAAAAA'+'LL'))`

Comment: Thanks Ashwini. I ended up with.
a=set([i for i in permutations('AAAAAA'+'LL')])
>>> for x in a:
 if 'LL' in "".join(x)

Comment: @Neil for your set `a` use : `sum('LL' in "".join(x) for x in a)`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than calculating permutations of `'A' * 60 + 'B' * 20` (which will return a lot of duplicates), you can represent the possible strings as combinations of 20 integers (representing the positions of the B's) taken from `range(80)`.  These combinations can be calculated using [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations): `itertools.combinations(range(80), 20)`.  This cuts the number of strings you have to examine down to only... uh... 3,535,316,142,212,174,320, which is at least a lot less than 80! ≈ 7×10^118, the number of results for the permutation way.  Fortunately, `itertools.combinations` returns an iterator, so just iterate over the expression with a for loop in which you test the lists of integers to see if any pairs are 1 apart.

Answer (score 0):

The unique permutations are:

```
 from itertools import permutations
 unique=set([i for  i in permutations('AAAAAA'+'LL')])
```

I think the best answer, isntead of having a very vague discussion is: take a look in the [itertools module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), 
it has some nice goodies for you.

Comment: How do I loop through that to get the number of tuples that have L consecutive?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - In my question I have "then find the number of times that there is BB somewhere in the results"

Comment: @Neil My bad, the question was not not formatted properly so I missed that detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import combinations
n_A, n_B = 60, 20
total = n_A + n_B
for pos in combinations(range(total), n_B):
    pos = sorted(pos)
    good = sum( i1 + 1 == i2 for i1, i2 in zip(pos, pos[1:]))
    if good:
        l = [ 'B' if i in pos else 'A' for i in range(total) ]
        print "".join(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You guys accept answers way to early: Here is a very short solution:

There are (60+20)!/(60!*20!) = ~3.53*10^18 possible permutations of 60 As and 20 Bs. 
Now you only have to subtract the cases, which doesn't contain the sequence 'BB'. This can be a bit tricky:

The interesting sequences have the following form:

```
A....ABA....ABA....ABA.... ....ABA....A
<----> <----> <----> <---- ----> <---->
  n1  1  n2  1  n3  1  n4   n20 1 n21
```

So there are alternately n1 As, then 1 B, then n2 As, then 1 B, ...

We know: n1 + 1 + n2 + 1 + n3 + ... + n20 + 1 + n21 = 80

This is equal to: n1 + n2 + n3 + ... + n21 = 60.

Note that n1>=0, n1...n20>=1, n21>=0 (because the sequence can start or end with a B)

If we substitute: m1 = n1, m2 = n2 - 1, m3  = n3 - 1, m4 = n4 - 1, ..., m20 = n20 - 1 and m21 = n21 we get:

```
m1 + m2 + m3 + ... + m21 = 41 with n1 ... n21 >= 0
```

So we reduced your problem to a simple equation. How many different solutions are there? 
This can be solved with the [Stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)-concept (theorem two).

So the solution is C_41^{41+21-1} = C_41^61 = 61!/(41!*20!)

Therefore: How many permutations are there, with no subsequence of 'BB'?

```
80!/(60!*20!) - 61!/(41!*20!) = 3.529.079.495.508.414.925
```

No need for programming at all. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's just consider the candidate positions of B that are *not* consecutive:

For every starting position of the first B, you need to space by at least one A.  Use up all 20 Bs (along with 20 As), and you have a tail of A containing the remaining 40 As plus the one that occurs after the last B, so you have a tail of 41 As in total.

```
0        1         2         3         4                  7         8
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123...         ...01234567890
BABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABABAAAA               AAAAAAAAAAA

^___________minimal string____________^

                                       ^____________tail____________^
```

Now, to count all the possibilities here, let's consider how many positions we can move an `A` from the tail and insert it in the B-sequence.  You can move it *in front* of any `B`, and you'll get a new unique sequence.  Therefore you can move up to 41 As into any of 20 positions.

- If you move zero As, you get the string above, so there's just one possibility.
- If you move one A, there are 20 possibilities.
- If you move two As, you can do it in any of the 20 positions in any of the above possibilities for moving one A, and so you have 20<sup>2</sup>.
- If you move three As, it's 20<sup>3</sup>.  You can see what's happening here...

Equation 1: number of unique possibilities with non-consecutive Bs = **20<sup>0</sup> + 20<sup>1</sup> + 20<sup>2</sup> + 20<sup>3</sup> + ... + 20<sup>41</sup>**

As for the total number of possibilites, let's do the same and arrange all Bs with no gaps.  Now there's a tail of 60 As, which can be inserted in front of any of the 20 Bs.

Equation 2: total number of unique possibilities =  **20<sup>0</sup> + 20<sup>1</sup> + 20<sup>2</sup> + 20<sup>3</sup> + ... + 20<sup>60</sup>**

And to find the number of possibilities that *DO* have consecutive Bs, it's fair to say that it's everything except for the ones that *DON'T*.  That's going to be Eq 2 minus Eq 1.

Equation 3: number of unique possibilities with two or more consecutive Bs = **20<sup>42</sup> + 20<sup>43</sup> + 20<sup>44</sup> + ... + 20<sup>60</sup>**